# DNS setting to redirect abc.example.com properly?

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, redhat, redirect

I have two dedicated servers running Apache on RHEL5/CentOS.

The first is setup to be a name server for the domain 'www.example.com'

I need to set it up so that http://abc.example.com points to the second server. What command should I use or what file should I edit?

I think I have to set the 'A' record, but where do I do this in a redhat linux system?

Comment: Which DNS (name) server package did you install?

Comment: I have no idea what's in use - bind perhaps? All i know is that when setting up the name server for the domain (elsewhere), I used the IP addresses of our first server... How can I check the DNS server package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was mistaken in my assumptions. Neither of the servers had name servers. The domain name was registered at GoDaddy and we added the two IP addresses as 'A' DNS records.

Answer (score 0):

You say **The first is setup to be a name server for the domain 'www.example.com'**.  I'm hoping you mean it's setup for the domain **example.com**, with a host (A) record called **www**.  If not, you already have problems.

Assuming the domain is **example.com**, you need a **CNAME** (alias) record for **ABC**, pointing at **XYZ.example.com**.

Answer (score 0):

Do both servers have static IP's? If so, the abc should be an A record on the name server pointing to the IP address of the second server.